# How can I use wp_save_image_editor_file filter?

Tags: images, filters

I would like to use `wp_save_image_editor_file` filter, but there is no documentation on the internet. Also, it seems that no matter how many arguments I pass to the handler, all are null.

Comment: Could you please tell us for **what purpose** and **how** you want to use the filter?

Comment: @kaiser basically I want to do this: store all uploaded media on a different server (cdn or whatsoever). I managed to store all files, including image thumbnails, but I have some problems on moving edited images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter inside `~/wp-admin/includes/image.edit.php` looks like this:

```
apply_filters('wp_save_image_editor_file', null, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id);
```

So a callback would look like the following:

```
add_filter( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', 'wpse91038_saved_image_editor_file', 10, 5 );
function wpse91038_saved_image_editor_file( $saved, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id )
{
    var_dump( $saved );
    var_dump( $filename );
    var_dump( $image );
    var_dump( $mime_type );
    var_dump( $post_id );
    return $saved;
}
```

Right above the core filter, there's another filter:

```
apply_filters('image_editor_save_pre', $image, $post_id);
```

The result of this filter, is then used as the 3rd argument inside the `wp_save_image_editor_file`-filter.

Then there's another important thing to note: If your custom `wp_save_image_editor_file` callback/function returns anything that **is not `NULL`**, then the core function will abort:

```
if ( null !== $saved )
    return $saved;

return $image->save( $filename, $mime_type );
```

So you either do the `$image->save( $filename, $mime_type );` **inside** your callback, or you will be left with an image that doesn't get saved. And if you want to do so, then better don't return the `$saved` with no value/`NULL`.

Comment: @Marius.Radvan Then please mark it as "solution" by checking the check mark below the voting arrows. Thanks.

Comment: I will have one more question - since I only return $saved which is null, how can I change the filename saved in the database for the edited file? Eg: in this handler I make some more modifications to the file, saved it to altered($filename), then I want to add in the database the new filelocation

Comment: @Marius.Radvan Just read the last paragraph of the answer again. :)